# Is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x-y) = - \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x-y)$?

Tags: derivatives

This seems intuitively plausible to me. But the notation sort of gets in the way when trying to prove this exactly. In particular when using the chain rule to write $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x-y) = - f'(x-y)$ the $'$ *looses* the information that the chain rule has already been applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us define $u = x-y$ then we can say
$$
f(x-y) = f(u).
$$
This is great, but we need to transform our derivatives which becomes
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{d}{d u} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\frac{d}{d u} 
$$
respectively. 
We now sub in the derivatives that we multiple the $u$-derivative by as
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 1\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -1
$$
Thus we have
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x-y) = 1\cdot \frac{d}{d u} f(u) = \frac{df}{du}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x-y) = -1\cdot \frac{d}{d u} f(u) = - \frac{df}{du}
$$
or
$$
-\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x-y) = \frac{df}{du} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x-y).
$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I understand your difficulty, but see if this helps.  It is, I hope, clear that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\sin(x-y)=\cos(x-y)$$
and
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\sin(x-y)=-\cos(x-y)\ .$$
The case you have described is really no different from this.

**Afterthought**.  You say that the $f'$ "loses the information that the chain rule has been applied" - well I would say almost the opposite.  It shows clearly that differentiation has been applied.  OK, it isn't clear whether you used the chain rule, the product rule or whatever; but, after all, this is not really important - what is important is that you have calculated the derivative.

Comment: I'm going over this again mentally. I guess I'm realizing just now that I never paid attention to the difference between $f'(x-y)$ and $(f(x-y))'$.

Comment: Actually it's more like $f(x-y) = f(z(x,y))$ is a *single* variable function in $z=x-y$, which itself is a function of two parameters $x$ and $y$, so the 'prime' can be understood as the derivative with respect to $z$, and neither $x$ nor $y$. But without proper notation this fact is not immediately obvious, which is why I don't particularly like it.

Comment: In fact the reason 'prime' can be written as all is *because* $f$ is a single variable function. Otherwise if $f=f(x,y)$ then $f'(x,y)$ would of course make no sense

Comment: Let me rephrase. I never consciously thought about the difference between $f'(g(x))$ and $(f(g(x)))'$.

Comment: @SebastianOberhoff there's no difference, both $f'(x)$ and $(f(x))'$ mean the same thing. The issue is not *where* the prime is placed, but *with respect to which variable* it's acting on. See my answer.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's incorrect. It's just ambiguous.

Comment: I retract my statement. They don't mean the same thing. However I maintain that it's not incorrect. Ambiguous doesn't mean incorrect, David. You gave it an interpretation that makes sense, so I don't see the problem here.

Comment: I'd even say that you're wrong because notations like $(f(g(x))'$ or $(f(x)g(x))'$ show up all the time

Answer (score 0):

We can write

$$ g(x,y) = f(z(x,y)) $$

where $z = x-y$. Then $f$ is a single-variable function in $z$ with two parameters $x,y$. Then The notation $f'(x-y)$ means something like

$$ f'(z(x,y)) = \frac{df}{dz} $$

Now if we wanted to find the derivatives $f$ w.r.t $x$ and $y$ instead, then we can employ the multivariable chain rule
$$ \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{df}{dz}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 
\frac{df}{dz}\cdot 1 = f'(z) $$

$$ \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = \frac{df}{dz}\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 
\frac{df}{dz}\cdot (-1) = -f'(z) $$

We can revise notation to remove the $z$ dependency and get
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x-y) = f'(x-y) $$
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x-y) = -f'(x-y) $$

In this form, it can be unclear what 'prime' means. It's w.r.t to *neither* $x$ nor $y$ but instead an implicit variable defined as $z=x-y$.

If you're used to this short-form notation, you can derive more complicated relationships such as
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x^2+y^2) = 2x\ f'(x^2+y^2) $$
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(e^x\sin y) = e^x\cos y \ f'(e^x \sin y) $$

and so on.